# Ant's echo-task and line-wraping

Tags: xml, ant, echo

We need to echo some fairly long strings, and the ant-script would look better with the lines *wrapped*.

```xml
<echo file="my.log">Really loooong line, that needs to appear without line breaks in the output, but which I'd still like to wrap in the ant-script</echo>
```

In general line-wrapping in XML is up to the application -- so my question is specific to the ant-application. Can I add line-breaks *somehow* to the above example, yet still have each line appear unbroken in the output?

(Escaping the newlines with the backslash (`\`) does not work...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the string in a property, line-broken as you see fit, then use that property in the echo task.

Something like this:

```
<property name="string" value="Really loooong line,
that needs to appear without line breaks in the output,
but which I'd still like to wrap in the ant-script." />    
<echo>${string}</echo>
```

Produces this output:

```
[echo] Really loooong line, that needs to appear without line breaks in the output, but which I'd still like to wrap in the ant-script.
```

As opposed to:

```
<echo>Really loooong line,
that needs to appear without line breaks in the output,
but which I'd still like to wrap in the ant-script.</echo>
```

Which produces

```
[echo] Really loooong line,
[echo] that needs to appear without line breaks in the output,
[echo] but which I'd still like to wrap in the ant-script.
```

Or put the string in the message parameters instead, which also works:

```
<echo message="Really loooong line,
that needs to appear without line breaks in the output,
but which I'd still like to wrap in the ant-script." />
```

Comment: But then the `<property>` line becomes just as unwieldy as the original `<echo>` line was -- the code just as ugly, and only harder to read because of the need to lookup the referenced properties.

Comment: How about the the message="" option?

Comment: Yay, that works indeed! Can I embed properties/variables in the message, when it is an attribute like this?

Comment: Yes, you can use properties in parameters.

Comment: I tested this method and it is _almost_ perfect. Unfortunately, if I indent the line-continuations inside the `message`-attribute, the pieces will be joined with _two_ blanks instead of one. This puzzles me... I suppose, we can avoid the indentation, but would've preferred not to...